# Reasonable SHA1 hash length for a specific number of values

Tags: encryption, hash, sha

I have a list of approx. 2500 images. For each image I create a SHA1 hash with which i can reference each picture. I also use the hashes to find duplicate images in the list.

By default, SHA1 hashes are 40 characters long. Currently I cut the hashes down to the first 7 characters.
Is this a reasonable length or is the collision propability too high?

Comment: What probability is acceptable?

Comment: referring to ANYthing with truncated *(!!)* hashes is **never** a good idea. Instead, you should generate unique IDs like ascending numbers and use them. Everything else will lead to confusion and/or software errors. Even use-cases like eclipse EGIT commit history hashes are ... very questionable although they're not actually used except for display purposes

Comment: Ascending numbers will not provide information on images being identical. As for truncation, each bit is essentially independent so truncation does not reduce the "randomness" and is done routine with larger hashes when a subset is needed such as a 16-byte IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probability is acceptable?

Note: a SHA1 hash is 20-bytes, do you mean 40-hexadecimal characters?

7 hex characters would be 7*4 = 28-bits.

From the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table), looking at 32-bits and 2900 elements the probability is .01% for a collision which IMO is not good enough.

Why not just use the full hash and 20-bytes instead of hexadecimal?

Comment: I want to export the hashes to an XML file, so I need the hash as a string.

Comment: In that case you will probably need more hex characters. If there are going to be many user you need to factor that in.